# Making list elements appear on sibling hover

Tags: html, css, joomla, responsive

I'm attempting to create a CSS-only responsive navigation bar within the Joomla CSS, and so far the navigation bar works for large screens and scales for small screens.  However, I am unable to get all other list elements in the menu to appear when hovering over the generated menu icon.  I have played around for two hours with manipulation of the >, ~, and + selectors, but it doesn't seem to work.

To reiterate/simplify, I want the other li elements to appear in the small screen version when hovering over the displayed icon.  Is this possible as a pure CSS solution?

Current implementation is found below.

Website: http://2017.grooverjazz.nl/

HTML mark-up:

```
<header>
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigationbar" style="xhtml" />
     <a href="#" class="collapseicon">&#9776;</a>
</header>
```

Current navigation bar CSS:

```
header {
  background: #12171d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #da8203;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 8vw;
}

header li:first-child {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

header li a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  color: #cccccc;
  padding: .7em .7em;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.collapseicon {
  padding: 0 9vw 0 0;
  float: right;
}

.collapseicon:hover > header li {
  display: inline!important;
}

@media (min-width: 950px) {
  header li a:hover {
    border-color: #da8203;
  }

  header li {
    display: inline!important;
  }

  header li a {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  header li:last-child {
    float: right;
  }

  .collapseicon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not yet a previous sibling selector, so you have to change the order of the icon and the moduletable:

```
<header>
  <a href="#" class="collapseicon">☰</a>
  <div class="moduletable">
    <ul class="nav menu">
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </div> 
</header>
```

Then select the hidden `<li>` elements on hover of the icon like this:

```
.collapseicon:hover + .moduletable li {
  display: block;
}
```

As an alternative to the adjacent sibling (`+`) you can also use the general sibling (`~`) selector.